# MouseArea covering a QML Row (or, Auto-Sizing Image+Text)

Tags: qt, qml

**Summary**: How can I stick an icon next to text, without hardcoding dimensions, and wrap the both of them in a `MouseArea`...in a way that works inside a `GridLayout`?

---

I have created a QML layout that has rows of labels across from tappable "buttons". The buttons are an icon along with text:

[image: Two rows with two columns; the rightmost column has images and text inline]

To create the buttons I am using a `Row`, so that the two items stick together properly (without any hardcoded dimensions) and have an automatic size that the `GridLayout` can use:

```
GridLayout {
  columns:2; rowSpacing:30

  Text {
    text: audioServer.label
    Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft
  }

  Row {
    spacing:10; Layout.alignment:Qt.AlignRight
    Image { width:29; height:30; y:10; source:"qrc:/rescan.png" }
    Text  { text:"Find Another" }
  }

  Text {
    text: "System uptime "+system.uptime
    Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft
  }

  Row {
    spacing:10; Layout.alignment:Qt.AlignRight
    Image { width:29; height:30; y:10; source:"qrc:/restart.png" }
    Text  { text: "Restart" }
  }
}
```

I want to put a `MouseArea` around each button. If I put it inside a row, like this...

```
Row {
  Image { width:29; height:30; y:10; source:"qrc:/rescan.png" }
  Text  { text:"Find Another" }

  MouseArea {
    anchors.fill: parent
    onClicked: rescan()
  }
}
```

...then I get the (reasonable) error `QML Row: Cannot specify left, right, horizontalCenter, fill or centerIn anchors for items inside Row. Row will not function.` And, more importantly, the layout breaks (I think the Row gets zero width, so the GridLayout has it flow off the right side.)

I cannot move the `MouseArea` outside of the `GridLayout` like this...

```
GridLayout {
  ...
  Row {
    id: rescanButton
    Image { width:29; height:30; y:10; source:"qrc:/rescan.png" }
    Text  { text:"Find Another" }
  }
}
MouseArea {
  anchors.fill: rescanButton
  onClicked: rescan()
}
```

...because you can only anchor to siblings or parents.

But I cannot put the `MouseArea` inside the `GridLayout`, because then it will try to lay it out as an item.

**How can I get a MouseArea wrapping the buttons?**

It's acceptable to me to use a container other than `Row`, but I strongly prefer not to hard-code any text or container dimensions.

Comment: Why don't you just make the `MouseArea` a child of the `Image`?

Comment: A terrible hack is that you _can_ put the `MouseArea` as a child of the `GridLayout`; it will leave a blank cell for it, but using `anchors.fill:myButton` will cause the tap region to properly be around the button. You just have to put all the MouseArea at the beginning or end of the GridLayout, so that they don't leave holes in the middle.

Comment: @FilipHazubski Because I want the user to be able to tap anywhere on the image **or** the text that goes with it. The "rescan.png" is just the circled arrows, but the user should also be able to tap on "Find Another" and have it work.

Comment: You can make `MouseArea` a child of an `Image` but make its `width` equal `Image.width + Text.width + gapWidth`. :) I think you can define `id` property of `Image` and `Text` and it will be available only in the scope of the `Row` so `MouseArea` can use it.

Comment: Also (sorry for spamming but) you can make only `MouseArea` the child of the `Row`, make `Text` and `Image` children of the `MouseArea` and set its size according to children size.

Comment: @FilipHazubski Your first suggestion might work, but seems an inelegant hack. Your second suggestion does not work directly, because the image and text then overlap.

Comment: @FilipHazubski Ah, however, this works: `MouseArea{ width:childrenRect.width; height:childrenRect.height; Row { Image{} Text{} } }` If you care to post this an answer, I'll be happy to give you credit for it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With your help we have got this:

```
GridLayout {
  ...
  MouseArea {
    onClicked: rescan()
    width:  childrenRect.width
    height: childrenRect.height
    Row {
      Image { width:29; height:30; y:10; source:"qrc:/rescan.png" }
      Text  { text:"Find Another" }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Phrogz Yes. That is definitely better way. :)

Comment: just to be clear, `GridLayout` can easily be a `Rectangle`, in case someone gets to this answers and wonders about the `GridLayout`. It is just from the TO's question